# Fast method to decompress huffman and arithmetic encoded data

Tags: image-compression, video-compression, dynamic-range-compression

By nature, when decompressing huffman (and I assume also Arithmetic encoded data) we have to read it in bit by bit and then see how it traverses a huffman code tree that has the actual symbol value at each leaf node. Since processors are designed for byte or multiple byte read/write, this seems to be a **very** slow and inefficient process.

Since huffman coding and many other methods are used to encode image and video data which produces non-byte boundary aligned results, how do we speed up the decompression process? I would assume that instead of reading 1 bit at a time we read several bits or even bytes and then using some clever method, find all symbols in it at once. I think that this is how all codecs for video and image would work to decompress the compressed image data fast. However, this is only my assumption and I do not know of any details. Could someone kindly reveal the secret to me?

Comment: I've never implemented a speed-optimized source decoder so I don't know the answer. However, I'd suggest reading the source for gzip. It uses Huffman and it's open source.

Answer (score 1):

For actual implementations take a look at (C) programming codes for decoders.

Basically the process is simple, you create an abstraction such as

```
bits = get_bits(n)
```

Where, `n` is the n bits you want to read. the var `bits` is left aligned. It extracts it from some `byte_buffer` - say a 32 bit or 64 bit symbols.

> NOTE: All, practical codecs put major symbols at 'Byte aligned' even though >internal symbols can be bit by bit.

Now for the implementation efficiency part, basically, irrespective of what huffman code will come out to be, (and hence whatever be the required `n`).

this is how simple get_bits can be implemented:

```
// At start
frame_buffer = 0x4444 
bits_delivered = 0 

n = 1 
mask = 0x8000
bits = (mask & frame_buffer) >> 32-n
mask = mask >> n 
bits_delivered += n
if(bits_delivered == 32) 
    { load_framebuffer( &frame_buffer) }
```

(Actual code needs to take care of few more stuff boundary conditions) 
The actual data is first fetch into `frame_buffer` which is a 32 bit register inside ALU (actually 16/32/64 bit depending on type of CPU) and then rest of the processing is only inside ALU's registers only.

Only when you exhaust the frame_buffer, do you really flush that bit-buffer and get another integer from memory.

This is how it gets its efficient implementation. Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You basically described the process yourself. Say that the codes are at most $n$ bits long and you want to use $m \ge n$ bits at a time: you build a table with $2^m$ entries. Each entry will store the first symbol decodable from the sequence using the rightmost $k$ bits ($k \le n \le m$) and the number $k$.

Now you read $m$ bits from the stream (`cur`), keep $m$ more bits ready (`buf`), look in the table and you know the first symbol. Now you right shift `cur` of $k$ positions, move the rightmost $k$ bits from `buf` to the leftmost $k$ bits of `cur` and start again. As soon as `buf` is emptied, read anothr $m$ bits in.

$m$ should be of course some multiple of 8. The problem is that it can reasonably be 8 or 16. Nothing more, because such a table would be incredibly sparse and repeated. If you need something more, than more complex solutions exist, clustering codes by length and using a master table followed by multiple extension tables. Moreover an entry could have a list of decoded symbols if more than one fit in the $m$ bits.